# Membership identification

Tags: c, file-io

```
char membership[10],memberID[10];
int c;
float AfterDiscount;

printf("\nEnter Your Membership ID to get 5 percent discount: ");
scanf(" %s",&memberID);
member=fopen("Membership.txt","r");
fgets(membership,10,member);
    if(strcmp(membership,memberID)==0)
        {
        AfterDiscount=final*0.95;
        printf("Your final price after 5 percent discount is RM%6.2f",AfterDiscount);
        printf("Thank you to come again, our honour member.");
        fclose(member);
        return AfterDiscount;
        }

printf("The Member ID is not exist. Please kindly contact the adminstrator, 03-XXXXXXX\n");
fclose(member);
return 0;
```

I would like to identify the existence of membership which formed in "B123456789" pattern. And i created a list of membership and named "Membership.txt". But seems not working even though i entered a valid membership ID.

Comment: also, newline than are included in the membership perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) will read at most 10 - 1 = 9 characters, which means that the 10 character ID that you read will be missing its last character. Also your strings are only long enough to hold 9 characters + a `\0` terminator.

Change:

```
char membership[10],memberID[10];
```

to:

```
char membership[11],memberID[11];
```

and change:

```
fgets(membership,10,member);
```

to:

```
fgets(membership,sizeof(membership),member);
```

Comment: This only working fine when membership id is at the top line, so what i have to add so that the loop can scan every membership id in my .txt file?

Comment: You need to ask a new question to cover this problem, as it's more detailed than can reasonably be answered in a comment.